Need to setup Wildfly datasource without leading "/"
I've started working on a legacy app that uses a JDBC connection to access the database. The code looks pretty much like this:
public DbConnection( ) throws Exception {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/autoline");    
}

I'm using Wildfly 33 to run the app, but I have some trouble setting up the datasource in standalone.xml according to the name from the code. First of all, Wildfly needs a leading slash after the java: part, which prevents me from setting up the JDNI-name verbatim from the code.
The almighty ChatGPT mentioned the java:jboss/exported prefix, but setting it up like this also does not work:
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/java:comp/env/jdbc/autoline" pool-name="autolinePool" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/autoline_dev?useSSL=false</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security user-name="xyz" password="abc"/>
</datasource>

Accessing the database gives me an error like that:
09:42:54,731 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/jdbc/autoline -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.dispo.dispo.env.jdbc.autoline
09:42:54,732 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming@33.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:89)
09:42:54,732 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming@33.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:190)

Looks like, the comppart of my setup is somehow ignored.

The namespace you use should work, or you could simply use jdbc/autoline.
<datasource jndi-name="jdbc/autoline" pool-name="autolinePool" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/autoline_dev?useSSL=false</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security user-name="xyz" password="abc"/>
</datasource>

You then need to add a reference in a web.xml.
<web-app version="6.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/autoline</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>

If you cannot modify the web.xml in the deployment, you could use a deployment overlay.
